# breaking a string in python depending on character pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a string something like this:

```
a = '5:::{"test":[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":3}]}4:::{"something":[{"d":1,"e":2},{"d":2,"e":3}]}'
```

I would like to split this into a list with the values being:

```
['5:::{"test":[{"a":1,"b":2},{"a":2,"b":3}]}','4:::{"something":[{"d":1,"e":2},{"d":2,"e":3}]}']
```

I tried regular expressions like this:

```
b = re.findall(r'[0-9]:::.*(?=[0-9]:::)|(?=$)',a)
```

trying to match parts starting with a digit, followed by three colons, then any character until either a [0-9]::: is hit or the end of the string. This seems completely wrong but I'm at a loss on how to continue here.

Thx
Markus

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [lookahead assertion](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

```
re.findall(r'\d:::.+?(?=\d:::|$)', a)
```

Answer (score 2):

`(\d:::\{.*?\}(?=\d))|(\d:::\{.*?\})$`

http://regexr.com?34opb